# Angular firestore get single document

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angular5

angular firestore get document giving error during assignment.
data is visible in console log, but not working in other cases.

[image: Code]

[image: console]

Comment: You should use arrow function to retain context `this`. (`get().then((doc) =>`) And please don't post picture instead of code

Comment: thanks  yurzui it is working now... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should use arrow function to retain context `this`. (`get().then((doc) =>`)
As yurzui commented.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `.toPromise().`
For example, `this.docRef.get().toPromise().then((doc) => {...`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64835149/property-then-does-not-exist-on-type-observabledocumentsnapshotdocumentdata) for an example with Angular and Firestore