# Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>> Angular Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am trying to get a single document in firebase however it is giving me an error

Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<DocumentSnapshot>'.

I have followed the documentation on firebase
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

My service.ts code is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ViewReportService {

 

     constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }
    
      getPassengerReport(myDocument) {
        const passengerRef = this.firestore.collection("newPassenger").doc(myDocument);
        const data = passengerRef.get().then(function (doc) {
          console.log("Cached document data:", doc.data());
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log("Error getting cached document:", error);
        });
        return data
      }

}
```

Angular Component Code

```
    passengerData = this.service.getPassengerReport(passengerDocumentID);
    console.log(passengerData)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider that you are using Angular. One of the best practices in Angular is to use `Observable` rather than promises

Lets convert your function to return an `Obervable`

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ViewReportService {
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }
  getPassengerReport = (myDocument) => 
    this.firestore.collection("newPassenger").doc(myDocument).get()
}
```

In the above we have defined `getPassengerReport` as a function that returns the line `this.firestore.collection("newPassenger").doc(myDocument).get()` using **ES6** syntax

In your component file you can have

```typescript
 passengerData$ = this.service.getPassengerReport(passengerDocumentID);
```

And in you can wrap your html with

```html
<ng-container *ngIf='passengerData$ | async as passengerData'>

  <!-- HTML CODE HERE -->

</ng-container>
```

We use **async** pipe to subscribe to the `Observable`

Comment: Thanks a lot it , my problem now is when i put {{passenger}} on my html it says [object Object]. do i need to convert it to json? - Apologies i'm very new to angular and javascript

i have added the variables at the top passenger = []; 
  passenger$ : Observable<any>;

Comment: `[Object Object]` in the html is expected as `passenger` is an Object. If you would like to view the Object you can use the `json` pipe, something like `{{ passenger | json }}` Otherwise you can simply access the properties e.g if the passenger has a name property, then you can display this as `{{ passenger.name }}`

Answer (score 2):

`.then` is for the promise. Observable is a different thing than the promise, and you need to convert observable into promise like `something.toPromise().then()`.

But important thing you need to consider the subscribe, so you may need to add an operator `first()` for it.

So code should be `something.pipe(first()).toPromise().then()`

Please try the above thing.